# Tesseract: using long term short memory throws "unable to read cube language model"

Tags: c++, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract to identify the text in etchings on records, such as the following:

[image]

The [Tesseract command line documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage) suggests one can specify the "OCR Engine Mode" by passing an --oem flag. OCR Engine Mode 1 is a "Neural nets LSTM", which sounds promising. However, when I try to evoke that model with the following command:

```
tesseract etching.png stdout --oem 1
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Load): unable to read cube language model params from /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.01/share/tessdata/eng.cube.lm
Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Create): unable to init CubeRecoContext object
init_cube_objects(false, &tessdata_manager):Error:Assert failed:in file tessedit.cpp, line 210
Abort trap: 6
```

If I drop the `--oem` flag I get output (but it's nonsense). Does anyone know how to interpret this message, or what I can do to leverage the LSTM model? I'm on OSX...